# Exeception when using Android Design support library for API 19 devices

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-coordinatorlayout, androiddesignsupport

I am using Design support library in my code. I am able to run application for Android L devices. If run the application for Android API version 19 devices, it gives force close.
Below is the my XML code.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:tabGravity="fill" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_drawer_header"
        app:itemTextColor="#000000"
        app:menu="@menu/global" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am getting below force close when run application for API version 19 devices

```html
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jar1.loc/com.jar1.loc.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.jar1.loc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.jar1.loc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:192)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:234)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:152)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.jar1.loc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:192) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:234) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:152) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.jar1.loc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0c003d a=-1 r=0x7f0c003d}
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2073)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
02-09 23:09:43.003 18864-18864/com.jar1.loc E/AndroidRuntime:  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(Relative
```

I am extending AppCompatActivity in My Activity and also i am using Theme.AppCompat style.

Please help me to resolve this exeception?

Answer (score 1):

Read the original exception near the bottom:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0c003d a=-1 r=0x7f0c003d}

Make sure all the attributes are of the expected type.